# Looping through an array and adding an IF statement

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get my head around arrays, and using IF statements with them.

I have my array:

```
var queryAlias = $('.TableQuery > tbody > tr').map(function () {
var $td2 = $(this).children('td');
  return `${$td2.eq(2).html()}([${$td2.eq(0).html()}].[${$td2.eq(1).html()}]) AS ${$td2.eq(4).html()}`; 
}).get().join(', '); /* COUNT([TABLE].[FIELD]) AS ALIAS */
```

The array is taking data from some columns in my table, but what I want now is to run through the array and build a string based on the following condition, IF column 3 is null then add column 1 & 2 too a string:

```
$.each(queryAlias, function (index, value) {
  if ((`${queryAlias}`) == null) {
    queryAlias[index] = queryAlias[index];
  }
});
```

```js
var field = $("#qBuilerFields option:selected").text();
var table = $("#qBuilerMaintable option:selected").text();
var orderby = $("#qBuilerSortBy option:selected").val();
var expression = $("#qBuilerExpression option:selected").val();
var alias = $("#alias").val();

/* Add new row to table with customers choices */
if ($("#qBuilerExpression").val() == null) {
  var addToTable = "<tr style='table-layout: fixed; width: 25%'><td>" + table + "</td><td>" + field + "</td><td style='table-layout: fixed; width: 25%'>" + expression + "</td><td style='table-layout: fixed; width: 25%'>" + orderby + "</td><td style='table-layout: fixed; width: 25%'>" + "[" + field + "]" + "</td><td><p style='color: darkred; text - align: center' class='pointer RemoveUser'>&#10006</p></td></tr>";
  $("table tbody").append(addToTable);
} else {
  var addToTable = "<tr style='table-layout: fixed; width: 25%'><td>" + table + "</td><td>" + field + "</td><td style='table-layout: fixed; width: 25%'>" + expression + "</td><td style='table-layout: fixed; width: 25%'>" + orderby + "</td><td style='table-layout: fixed; width: 25%'>" + alias + "</td><td><p style='color: darkred; text - align: center' class='pointer RemoveUser'>&#10006</p></td></tr>";
  $("table tbody").append(addToTable);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Drop down showing tables, this will be table A for any query -->
<select class="select" id="qBuilerMaintable">
  <option value="" disabled selected>{ Select Table... }</option>
  <option value="">TableA</option>
  <option value="">TableB</option>
</select>

<!-- Drop down showing fields linked to table A -->
<select class="select" id="qBuilerFields">
  <option value="" disabled selected>{ Select Field... }</option>
  <option value="">Field1</option>
  <option value="">Field2</option>
</select>

<!-- Alias, this will be the name of the column header if they enter text here  -->
<input class="input" id="alias" type="text" placeholder="(optional) Enter Alias...  " name="alias" value="" />

<!-- Drop down giving ORDER BY choices -->
<select class="select" id="qBuilerSortBy">
  <option value="" disabled selected>{ Select Order By... }</option>
  <option value="ASC">Ascending</option>
  <option value="DESC">Descending</option>
</select>

<!-- Expression -->
<select class="select" id="qBuilerExpression">
  <option value="" disabled selected>{ Select An Expression... }</option>
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="count">Count</option>
  <option value="sum">Sum</option>
</select>

<table id="t01" class="TableQuery" style="table-layout:fixed">
  <thead>
    <tr style="table-layout:fixed">
      <th style="width:20%">Table</th>
      <th style="width:20%">Field</th>
      <th style="width:20%">Expression</th>
      <th style="width:10%">Order By</th>
      <th style="width:20%">Alias</th>
      <th style="width:10%">Remove</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="table-layout:fixed">

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your second code example makes almost no sense. It would help **a lot** to see the relevant HTML here.

Comment: where your confusion I think is coming from is you're iterating over an array's keys/values (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, etc), but each iteration the logic is only aware of the current array key and value, so i.e. you're only looking at `q[0]` the first iteration, you can't include logic there yet to look at `q[1]` because that will happen on the next iteration. So instead you just want to look at the whole array at once and add the logic like `if (q[2] == null) { return q[0] + q[1]; }`

Comment: I have added some more information to my initial description

Comment: Please update your question to show all relevant code. For instance, your JS is referencing `$("#qBuilerExpression")` but that ID doesn't exist in your posted HTML. Additionally, the JS vars `table`, `field`, `expression`, etc. aren't defined anywhere. You listed out 3 different JS functions, but it's not clear how these are connected or if there's more that's still missing. Provide a minimal, reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - the key here is *reproducible*.

Comment: Ive tried to tidy it up - hopefully done to standard

Comment: Your each statement can be formed a bit differently - check for null first and then iterate over the array. Also your queryAlias[index] = queryAlias[index] is redundant